# Unique Node Values using oXMLFile.SelectNodes

Tags: excel, vba

So I m dynamically generating my sheet names using the following code, by reading an XML File:

```
Set GenreNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/query/genre/text()")
.
.
Private Sub CreateSheet(sheetName)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:= _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    ws.Name = sheetName
End Sub
```

Works perfectly when using XML without repeaing similar genre tags like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <query id="bk101">
      <question>Do we have cloud security</question>
      <answer>Yes</answer>
      <genre>Cloud</genre>
   </query>
   <query id="bk102">
      <question>Do we have locks on the door</question>
      <answer>No</answer>
      <comment>We have fingerprint access.</comment>
      <genre>Physical Security</genre>
   </query>
</catalog>
```

Problem is, when I have repetitions in genre (SDLC) in this example, like :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <query id="bk101">
      <question>Do we have cloud security</question>
      <answer>Yes</answer>
      <genre>Cloud</genre>
   </query>
   <query id="bk103">
      <question>What SDLC Priciple is follwed?</question>
      <answer>None</answer>
      <comment>We have code ninjas.</comment>
      <genre>SDLC</genre>
   </query>
   <query id="bk104">
      <question>Do you have OSWP status?</question>
      <answer>None</answer>
      <comment>We plan to do next year.</comment>
      <genre>SDLC</genre>
   </query>
</catalog>
```

Excel gives me the `Name already exists` error. How do I extract unique node names that I don't have this error?

Thanks.

Comment: In your example, what is the sheet name that you would use instead of SDLC?

Comment: Simple solution would be to: everytime you add a sheet, add the name to a `dictionary`. Then just before you attempt to add a sheet, check the `dictionary` for the name and if it exists, don't add it

Comment: @Daniel Actually, I will have repeating genres, so making them unique does not make sense.

Comment: Need a bit more info I think. can you only use genre for sheet names? Do you want to add all entries as sheets or do you want to avoid duplicates? Can you not just suffix the query id to the genre?

Comment: @Absinthe I want to avoid duplicates and I can only use genres as sheet names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your sheet creation code so it doesn't try to create duplicate sheets:

```
Private Sub CreateSheet(sheetName)
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next '<< ignore error if sheet doesn't exist
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)
    On Error Goto 0      '<< stop ignoring errors

    If ws Is Nothing Then 
        'sheet doesn't exist, so create it.
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:= _
                 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = sheetName

    End If
End Sub
```